# History of Noble Savage idea

Tags: good-and-evil, human-nature

I used to believe that the idea of noble savage, that humans are innately well natured and corrupted into bad bahavior by socialization was originated by `Rousseau`. However, I just accidentally came upon `Mencius`, who predated Rousseau by about 2000 years and learned that he had a similar idea.

Is there any history of this (scientifically superseded) idea that revolves around the appeal to nature even before Mencius and who were some other exponents of that idea regardless of their position in history?

Comment: Mencius did not have the idea of the noble savage, so you're sourcing is off. He had the idea of the inherent goodness of humanity until corrupted (by upbringing) which is a bit different.

Comment: boils down to the same ballpark

Comment: I thought the term 'noble savage' went out during the early 20th century late 19th century with the collapse of the British empire. You may want to move your reading forward a few more decades...

Comment: Please google before asking here, Wikipedia has the [Pre-history of the noble savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_savage#Pre-history_of_the_noble_savage).

Comment: @amphibient: I don't recommend boiling your ball park, that's not medically advisable. But then all ships that pass in the night are grey.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the date of origin of the concept of 'the noble savage', you might find Bruce G. Trigger's 'Reviewed Work(s): The Myth of the Noble Savage by Ter Ellingson', The International History Review, Vol. 24, No. 1 (Mar., 2002), pp. 136-137, of interest. Note his remarks on Rousseau. In a very compressed nutshell, and gently put, since Rousseau did not endorse the idea of the noble savage neither Mencius or anyone else anticipated him in regard to it. Accepting with virmaior that Mencius did not have the idea of the Noble Savage, we appear to have a case of Mencius, who did not have the idea, not anticipating Rousseau, who also did not have the idea. Two interesting negatives ! But let's get down to answering the question as far as concerns Rousseau.

> Ter Ellingson. The Myth of the Noble Savage. Berkeley: University of California
>    Press, 2001. Pp. xxii, 445.
>
> Hoxie Fairchild, in his book The Noble Savage (1928), defined the Noble Savage
>    as 'any free and wild [human] being who draws directly from nature virtues which
>    raise doubts as to the value of civilization' (p. 2). The Noble Savage, according to
>    Fairchild, 'represents a protest against the evil incidental to human progress' (p.
>    2). Ter Ellingson demonstrates that the Noble Savage was a much rarer specimen
>    and with very different plumage than most scholars imagine.
>
> Ellingson traces the concept of the Noble Savage back to the French lawyer
>    Marc Lescarbot's account of the Micmac Indians he encountered in Acadia in
>    1606-7. Lescarbot's chief reason for calling them noble was that Indian men
>    hunted, which in France was one of the prerogatives of the nobility. Lescarbot
>    enumerated what he regarded as both the vices and the virtues of the Indians and
>    compared these attributes with those of Europeans. This pattern, followed at least
>    since thirteenth-century European descriptions of the Mongols, would persist into
>    the nineteenth century.

NB: the dating of the 'noble savage' to Lescarbot is a point I cannot verify. My main answer concerns Rousseau, however, and is unaffected by this point.

> After Lescarbot, Ellingson finds few traces of the concept of the Noble Savage
>    until the mid-nineteenth century. **Jean-Jacques Rousseau did not employ the term
>    or believe that primitive peoples could be either good or bad, as he held that this
>    distinction had evolved along with civilization.** The conceptualization of primitive
>    human beings acquired increasingly negative connotations as a result of Enlightenment progressivism, growing racism, and finally Darwinian evolution. Each of
>    these intellectual movements encouraged the view that early humans represented
>    the antithesis of European cultural achievements.

NB: The statement that 'Jean-Jacques Rousseau did not ... believe that primitive peoples could be either good or bad, as he held that this
 distinction had evolved along with civilization' needs examination, which I attempt below.

> Ellingson establishes that the concept of the Noble Savage was popularized,
>    beginning in 1859, by ... John Crawfurd... Crawfurd attributed the concept to social reformers and
>    anarchists, whom he accused of seeking to use unduly optimistic hypotheses about
>    human nature to promote their Utopian social agendas. ...
>
> Ellingson makes two important contributions to understanding the concept of
>    the Noble Savage. The first is establishing the rarity of this term between the times
>    of Lescarbot and Crawfurd. This conclusion can be confirmed by rereading Fairchild's voluminous survey of literature which he regarded as exemplifying the idea of the Noble Savage, but in which the term almost never occurs. Ellingson also
>    establishes that, from the early eighteenth to the middle of the nineteenth century,
>    accounts of indigenous peoples increasingly stressed their primitive and negative
>    characteristics to accord better with evolutionary and racist themes.
>
> Ellingson contends that Crawfurd fabricated the concept of the Noble Savage as
>    an 'apparent absurdity' (p. 2) intended to incite disbelief and facilitate rhetorical
>    attacks and even genocide against indigenous peoples, as well as to assert anthropology's fundamental loyalty to its own culture. These probably were Crawfurd's
>    goals, but his creation, as it was understood by others, appears to have elicited a
>    broader range of reactions than Ellingson considers. The Wendat historian and
>    philosopher, Georges Sioui, maintains that, regardless of their form, the Adario
>    dialogues published by the French nobleman baron de Lahontan, far from being
>    fantasies or fabrications, express beliefs that are authentically Wendat, and that
>    these and similar Amerindian ideas, when introduced to France, led directly to the
>    French Revolution. The substance of Lahontan's description of Huron values is
>    confirmed by the Jesuit Relations, which were not written by revolutionaries.
>
> Ethnographic data emanating from New France nourished the Enlightenment
>    belief in the essential goodness of humanity, while evidence that societies did not
>    have to be based on hereditary classes, physical coercion, or rampant social in-
>    equality has played a significant role in reshaping Western societies over the past
>    250 years. Lewis Henry Morgan, Karl Marx, and some modern anthropologists
>    have envisaged social evolution as a project that ideally recreates the desirable aspects of simpler, more egalitarian societies within the context of technologically
>    advanced civilizations. Romantics disgruntled by modern industrial societies have
>    consistently idealized simpler ones. For people who know nothing about Crawfurd, the Noble Savage has become a label for what they admire about small-scale
>    societies. The concept of the Noble Savage, as it is understood today, is neither all
>    positive nor all negative in terms of its conceptualizations and impacts; like most
>    concepts in the social sciences, it is multivalent and contested.

## Natural goodness and badness

> In the part 1 of the Second Discourse [Rousseau] describes
>    our original or natural condition through a portrait of
>    savage man's basically solitary existence in the pure
>    state of nature. In the part 2 he discusses the state of
>    nature simply - the prepolitical condition eventually
>    ended by the social contract (John T. Scott, 'The Theodicy of the Second Discourse: The "Pure State of Nature" and Rousseau's Political
>   Thought', The American Political Science Review, Vol. 86, No. 3 (Sep., 1992), pp. 696-711: 696).

**State of nature**

> The pure state of
>    nature in the Second Discourse is the condition where
>    humans exist as purely physical beings, that is,
>    possessed solely of the instincts, passions, and faculties with which they are endowed by (physical)
>    nature. Humans originally or naturally lack moral
>    needs or passions, that is, needs or passions with
>    particular, conscious regard for their fellow humans.
>    Such needs and passions, Rousseau argues, only
>    develop when individuals begin to have constant
>    relations with their fellow humans. Rousseau defines
>    a moral being as "intelligent, free, and considered in
>    its relations with other beings" (1964, 94). The natural
>    man whom he describes in the pure state of nature is
>    manifestly not a moral being according to his definition: while he may be said to be "free" in the sense
>    that he enjoys "natural freedom" (p. 127)-or what
>    Rousseau equates with "an unlimited right to everything that tempts him and that he can get" (Social
>    Contract 1.8), he is not "intelligent" nor does he have
>    "relations with other beings" or the passions associated with such relations. (Scott: 699; Rousseau, Jean-Jacques. 1964. The First and Second Discourses.
>    Trans. Roger D. and Judith R. Masters. New York: St.
>    Martin's; 94, 127.)

In the pure state of nature, then, it **looks** as if human beings cannot be either morally good or morally bad. But is the appearance the reality ?

For :

> Rousseau claims that he has demonstrated that man
>    is naturally good and that he has thereby justified
>    nature (Masters: 1964, 193). He later explains that the natural
>    goodness of man is central to his system of thought,
>    as when he exposed the "fundamental principle" of
>    all of his writings, namely, "that man is naturally
>    good, loving justice and order, that there is no
>    original perversity in the human heart, and that the
>    first movements of nature are always right" (1959-69,
>    vol. 4, pp. 935-36). Rousseau's demonstration of the
>    natural goodness of man in the Second Discourse
>    consists in his portrait of savage man's natural condition in the pure state of nature as a physical being
>    embedded in (physical) nature. ...[L]et me take up what Rousseau means by
>    our natural goodness.
>
> We usually brand attributions of goodness as moral
>    judgments - even as matters of "value" distinct from
>    those of "fact." Rousseau, however, does not use
>    good in a moral sense and even takes it in a sense
>    compatible with matters of physics. Rousseau's conception of goodness becomes clear when, after his
>    description of the pure state of nature, he wonders
>    what kind of mortality we could be said to possess by
>    nature:
>
> > It seems at first that men in that state, not having
> >      amongst themselves any moral relationship or known
> >      duties, could be neither good nor evil, and had neither
> >      vices nor virtues: unless, taking these words in a physical
> >      sense, one calls vices in the individual the qualities that
> >      can harm his own preservation, and virtues the those
> >      that can contribute to it; in which case, it would be
> >      necessary to call the most virtuous the one who least
> >      resists the simple impulses of nature. (Masters: 1964, 128)

But Rousseau wants to add that it is perfectly possible for human beings to act as morality requires, and thus to love justice and order and to fulfil morally right intentions, without having any *concept* of morality. So it is misleading for Scott to say that 'Rousseau, however, does not use
 good in a moral sense'. He *does*. Only, in the state of nature we act morally without knowing that we do.

In other words by 'the simple impulses of nature' human beings, whether in the relatively solitary pure state of nature or in what Rousseau calls merely the 'state of nature' in Part II of the Second Discourse, where there are multiple and regular social interactions but before the competitive emotions mediated by the institution of private property set in, human beings can act as morality requires and have a spontaneous inclination to do so with yet 'no idea of moral goodness.

Comment: "Bon sauvage" is the french equivalent and Montaigne's development of the idea is famous. French wikipedia lists precedents as early as 1500.

Comment: @sand1. Thanks for this information. I have revised my answer, the main substance of which remains : Rousseau did not endorse the idea of the noble savage and so the question of who anticipated him in regard to it, and when, doesn't arise. Or so it seems to me. But I appreciate your scholarly intervention.  I'm always anxious to remove errors. I owe you. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas your point is not only wrong, but it's also highly subjective. You (and apparently the guy you quote) confuse science/facts with opinion/ideology. And that's exactly what discredit anthropology (and most globally the social sciences). An example: `British amateur anthropologist John Crawfurd, a racist and political conservative`. Unlike ideology for science, it's not the virtue of the source
that counts (his opinion, status, popularity), and the sweetness of the argumentation, but *facts*.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas I'm curious: what is the difference between an "amateur" anthropologist and a "true anthropologist"?

Comment: I have revised portions of my account of Rousseau in the light of JinSnow's highly pertinent objections. This does not imply JinSnow's agreement with my amended text.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas You are quite a surprising fellow. Your humility touches me. A classical answer, (the natural one, of human "state of nature"? ;-) ) would have replied the criticism with the exact opposite: it would have fought back, and certainly not have upvoted the opponent answer. I disagree with you on that topic (I believe "innocence" is "virtue") but I like you (I like your civilized/unnatural moral judgment ;-) ). The cultural evolution never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Thank you for your own, most civilised comment. My text was misleading (or worse) as it stood and couldn't be left as it was. You made me re-think. I can only be grateful for that. Best - Geoffrey

Answer (score 4):

A part of the answer:

It's true that:

- Rousseau did not invent the Noble Savage idea, which is much older (cf. below).
- It's also true that he never used the phrase “noble savage” (or “the good savage”)

But Geoffrey Thomas Statement `"Rousseau did not endorse the idea of the noble savage"` is false.  Rousseau writing shows that he clearly believes in it. He believed that humans in the state of nature were blissful, nonviolent, altruistic, and non-competitive and that people were generally “nice” to each other. He believed that evil was foreign to mankind's deep nature, that it was merely a perversion.

So, he was carrying this belief (like many intellectuals of his time [and ours]), and he contributed to promoting it.

Rousseau wrote:

> So many authors have hastily concluded that man is naturally cruel, and requires a regular system of police to be reclaimed; whereas nothing can be more gentle than him in his primitive state when placed by nature at an equal distance from the stupidity of brutes and the pernicious good sense of civilized man…. The more we reflect on this state, the more convinced we shall be that it was the least subject of any to revolutions, the best for man and that nothing could have drawn him out of it but some fatal accident, which, for the public good, should never have happened. The example of the savages, most of whom have been found in this condition, seems to confirm that mankind was formed ever to remain in it, that this condition is the real youth of the world, and that all ulterior improvements have been so many steps, in appearance towards the perfection of individuals, but in fact towards the decrepitness of the species.

It's pretty clear in French:

> le principe de toute morale (...) est que l'homme est un être
> naturellement bon, aimant la justice et l'ordre ; qu'il n'y a point de
> perversité originelle dans le coeur humain, et que les premiers
> mouvements de la nature sont toujours droits"
>
> (...) tous les vices qu'on impute au cœur humain ne lui sont point
> naturels (...) par l'altération successive de leur bonté originelle,
> les hommes deviennent enfin ce qu'ils sont.
>
> rien n’est si doux que lui dans son état primitif, lorsque, placé par
> la nature à des distances égales de la stupidité des brutes et des
> lumières funestes de l’homme civil, et borné également par l’instinct
> et par la raison à se garantir du mal qui le menace, il est retenu par
> la pitié naturelle de faire lui-même du mal à personne, sans y être
> porté par rien, même après en avoir reçu. Car, (...) il ne saurait y avoir d’injure où il n’y a point de propriété.
>
> l’homme naît bon, c’est la société qui le corrompt
>
> Le principe de toute morale (...) est que l'homme est un être
> naturellement bon, aimant la justice et l'ordre ; qu'il n'y a point de
> perversité originelle dans le coeur humain, et que les premiers
> mouvements de la nature sont toujours droits" (...) tous les vices
> qu'on impute au cœur humain ne lui sont point naturels (...) par
> l'altération successive de leur bonté originelle, les hommes
> deviennent enfin ce qu'ils sont.

Source:

- Rousseau, Lettre à C. de Beaumont. Novembre 1762. La Pléiade, IV, p. 935 à 937.
- Discours sur l'origine et les fondements de l'inégalité parmi les hommes
  By Jean-Jacques Rousseau

### Concerning the history of this myth

The noble savage idea myth is older than Rousseau (1750)

- in 1670 John Dryden’s wrote in The Conquest of Granada

> I am as free as Nature first made man, Ere the base laws of servitude
> began, When wild in woods the noble savage ran.

As Pinker explains in The Blank Slate: "The concept of the noble savage was inspired by European colonists’ discovery of indigenous peoples in the Americas, Africa, and (later) Oceania. It captures the belief that humans in their natural state are selfless, peaceable, and untroubled, and that blights such as greed, anxiety, and violence are the products of civilization."

**But the noble savage idea is older, and even much older (and probably as old as the second generation of homo sapiens) if you include on it the narcissist declaration "mankind is naturally so virtuous", or the "before it was better", or the concept of "we have been perverted by the progress/wealth, etc."**

For instance:

- In 1603 Shakespeare wrote in Hamlet:

> What a piece of work is a man! How noble in reason! How infinite in
> faculty! In form, in moving, how express and admirable! In action, how
> like an angel! In apprehension, how like a god!

The idea that wisdom comes from a distant past (so before we have been perverted by [something]) has been found in one of the oldest writings (which suggests it's much older): 4500 years ago, Shuruppak's instructions begin by recalling "those far remote days" and "those far remote years" as the source of wisdom.

In the old days, a few decades after using the fire, some cave men Dudes might have blamed this "technological progress that perverted the people" of his time. He might have tried to live without fire, to find back the virtuous life his ancestors had before the great perversion (Some associate virtue with harmonious behavior, while others associate it with wisdom, virility or anything else since the concept of virtue depends on many things.).

Savages too ―like us― believed in noble savage.

(And in our turn, we might be seen as noble savages in few thousand years. But I doubt it. I bet we'll be only seen as savage since we'd have left too many footprints of who we are! Greetings to the future ―if we manage to make it!)

Comment: +1. A very good answer, which I am glad to upvote. Just a detail : do you equate 'good' and 'noble' ('*bon* and *noble*? It doesn't seem an exact equation to me, but I ask openly and not critically.

Comment: I have revised my answer in the light of JinSnow's highly pertinent objections.

Answer (score 0):

This grows increasingly more interesting. In classical Greece, there was a myth of the golden age, which didn't characterize its people as savages or not, but fits with the idea of a time of innocence and happiness long ago, which unfortunately ended as life deteriorated to our present miserable state. Here's Wikipedia [Wikipedia on the Ages of Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_Man):-

> The Greek poet Hesiod (between 750 and 650 BC), in his poem Works and Days (lines 109–201). Golden Age – The Golden Age is the only age that falls within the rule of Cronus. Created by the immortals who live on Olympus, these humans were said to live among the gods and freely mingled with them. Peace and harmony prevailed during this age. Humans did not have to work to feed themselves, for the earth provided food in abundance. They lived to very old age but with a youthful appearance and eventually died peacefully.

Silver, Bronze, Heroic ages followed and the present is an Iron Age. Plato took up the idea and adapted it into his own account of the ideal state. The story was a trope throughout the classical period in Greece and Italy. (Ovid has another version.)

I may be generalizing the idea too far, but the story of Adam and Eve in Genesis also presents the idea of a long-ago time when human life was innocent and better.

Perhaps we should not be looking for an origin of this idea, but tracing a theme that constantly reappears throughout history.